# Why does the hasNext() method not work for this example?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        Map<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            String phnum = sc.nextLine();

            phoneBook.put(name, phnum);
            sc.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Not Found");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();

            if (phoneBook.get(s) == null)
                System.out.println("Not Found");
            else
                System.out.println(s + "=" + phoneBook.get(s));
            sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think hasNext is not working? Did you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Please elaborate the problem statement ,sharing code does not helps us to understand the end goal.

Comment: hasNext() is working. Any other issues?

Comment: always use brackets in if-statements to achieve basic maintainability!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] argh) {

    Map<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println(" Enther the Size of Phone book : ");
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Name :");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Phone No :");
        String phnum = sc.nextLine();

        phoneBook.put(name, phnum);

       // sc.nextLine();

    }
   System.out.println("***Search Phone Numbers (enter Name)***\n");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        String s = sc.nextLine();

        if (phoneBook.get(s) == null) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + "=" + phoneBook.get(s));
        }
        //sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```